# Homotopy groups of the Grassmannians

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, grassmannians

What are the homotopy groups of the oriented Grassmannian $Gr^{+}(p,q)$ (p-planes in $R^{p+q}$) $\pi_{r}(Gr^{+}(p,q))$, $r \le pq$?

Do you know any references on the web about it?

Comment: This is about as hard as computing the homotopy groups of spheres; for example, $Gr^{+}(2, 2)$ is $S^2 \times S^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $r=<p.q$?

Comment: Perhaps a better place to start, Renan, is *what do you need to know* about these groups, or what information would help you?

Comment: I mean r less or equal than the dimension of the grassmannia Gr (p,q)

Comment: Prof Budney, I just would like to know, if there exists such a description, the r-homotopy groups of the  Grassmannian for r less or equal than the dim of the grassmannian itself. Sorry if I don't  manage to be more specific, but it is exactly because I don't understand what can appears there....

Comment: Thanks everybody for replying. I know that the r-th homotopy groups of $S^k$ are a difficult problem for r bigger than k. In this case, I am only interested in the case r smaller  or equal to p.q = dim Gr (p,q).